# Native android screen sharing by using WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc

I am developing new android application where I have a button with name "Share your screen". On clicking this button, my app will start sharing customer's android phone screen to agent on web browser. For this I am using WebRTC but I didn't find good tutorial to implement the same. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't support screen-sharing from Android yet (it may in the future).  I don't know if Chrome or Opera do, but I suspect they don't either.